# How to write a script bash to enter multi-line input in jupyter-notebook?

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I needed to write a script with configuration environment in only one cell. I want to leave it indented

```
!(python --version
 which python
 pip --version 
 conda --version 
 which conda) >> config-environment.txt
```

But cell not acept skip line between each command. How to write? Is it possible write bash script with indented in jupyter-notebook?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For your particular case, you can simply use semicolon at the end to run it i.e.

```
!(python --version; \
 which python; \
 pip --version; \
 conda --version; \
 which conda) >> config-environment.txt
```

For general case, you can use [`%%bash`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-bash) cell magic command to run the cell in bash i.e.

> %%bash script magic
>
> Run cells with bash in a subprocess.

```
%%bash

(python --version
 which python 
 pip --version 
 conda --version 
 which conda) >> config-environment.txt
```

You can also have a look at [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) python module.